# C# Interface MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a User class that also includes a Card interface:

```
internal class User {
  [BsonId, BsonElement("_id"), BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public uint Balance { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string IBAN { get; set; }
    public Card Card { get; set; }
}
```

Inferface:

```
 interface Card
    {
        //something
    }

    class Silver : Card
    {
        
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public int Tax { get; set; } = 30;
    }

    class Gold : Card
              
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public int Tax { get; set; } = 20;
    }
```

I managed to add the user to the database, but the problem appears when I try to retrieve it:

System.FormatException: 'An error occurred while deserializing the Card property of class User: Unknown discriminator value 'Gold'.'

```
            var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq("Username", user.Username);
            User search = Globals.m_Collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
```

MongoDB:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"6341dc42320d14432897ce2d"},"Username":"tttt","Password":"cgJvBm6bI+JIjwdnq2PB3XF0leXevEZ2sLliffeu6Tw=","Balance":{"$numberInt":"0"},"Country":"Filand","First_Name":"S","Last_Name":"S","IBAN":"FL79BNKSS32075116","Cardul":{"_t":"Gold","Number":"833067132","Tax":{"$numberInt":"20"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding BsonDiscriminator to your derived classes

```
[BsonDiscriminator("Gold")]
class Gold : Card
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public int Tax { get; set; } = 20;
}
```

Comment: The solution I found is for Card to be an abstract class, not an interface, because "BsonDiscriminator" doesn't work on the interface